# Spell Check Error in LibreOffice - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, spell-checking

Spell library package already installed in Ubuntu 12.04, even though LibreOffice is not able to find out Spelling errors in a file.

How can I fix this? Is there is any other office available for Free in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Just type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install myspell-en-us
```

Restart libre office, see it is working ?

or you can try, **Options > Language Settings > Languages > under default languages for documents, set Western language as English (USA)**

if nothing is working you have another options like :

openoffice

Word processor

Calligra Suite

SoftMaker Office

king soft off.